# Python Flask Mailchimp signup

Tags: python, flask, mailchimp

I'm trying to use PostMonkey & Flask to HTTP GET an email address (from a from on my website) and then subscribe this to the specified list.

It works and sends the email requesting the user to confirm the subscription, but either server error 500's or when debug mode is on it comes up with

> TypeError: signup() takes no arguments (2 given)

Here's my code:

```
@app.route("/signup", methods=['GET'])
def signup():

    try:
        email = request.args.get('email')
        pm.listSubscribe(id="cdc2ba625c", email_address=email)

    except MailChimpException, e:

        print e.code
        print e.error
        return redirect("/")

return signup
```

I'm not sure what's causing it and it's been bugging me for a while!

Comment: what is the "return signup" line for ?

Comment: it's just there until i have it display a thank you page, not exactly needed at the moment

Comment: Flask view must return `Response` object or tuple `(response, status_code, headers)`.

Comment: Yeah i fixed it, i had it return a template and it seemed to work ok. Thanks for the help, i guess when you stare at something long enough you don't spot the obvious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested the problem was related to my 'Return' statement, turns out flask doesn't like returning nothing.

```
@app.route('/signup', methods=['POST'])
def signup():

    try:
        email = request.form['email']
        #email = request.args.get('email')
        pm.listSubscribe(id="cdc2ba625c", email_address=email, double_optin=False)

    except MailChimpException, e:

        print e.code
        print e.error
        return redirect("/")

    return render_template('index.html')
```

Thanks to all those that commented back